# How can inject extra functionality to a existing object method?

Tags: javascript, object

Suppose I have a obj,

```
var obj = {
     l:function(){
            alert(1);
     }
}
```

How can I add some more functionality to obj.l without editing the obj?

Comment: What do you mean by "editing the obj"?

Comment: You will want to have a look at aspect-oriented programming.

Answer (score 3):

> without editing the obj?

If you mean without modifying the object, you can't. If you mean without editing the *source code* of the object, you can add functionality at the beginning and/or at the end, but not in the middle.

```
(function() {
    var original = obj.l;
    obj.l = function() {
       var retval;

       // You can do something here

       // Call the original
       retVal = original.apply(this, arguments);

       // You can do something here

       // Return result
       return retVal;
    };
})();
```

The scoping function there is just to avoid making `original` available to any other code.

That example of calling the original will call it with the same `this` and list of arguments that your wrapper was called with. You can, of course, pass it different arguments instead, perhaps via `Function#call` instead of `Function#apply`.

Comment: you could use a closure for the `obj.l`

Comment: @NinaScholz: Well, the code probably will be in a closure. :-) But yes, an all-in-one is possible. (I added a boring scoping function rather than an all-in-one.)